# Java: How to have a count each time a letter is Displayed

Tags: java

I am trying to make a program the will count 1 each time a particular letter is displayed.  So I want it to show A: 4 if AAAA was entered. I have been working for hours on this but I have not been able to get it to work.  Would there be any way to do this without a array also?
This is the code that I have at the moment.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
     Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
     String A;
     String B;
     A = kb.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Person A: Please enter your amount of wins");
     B = kb.nextLine();
     System.out.println("Player B: Please enter your amount of wins");
     kb.nextLine();
     if()
} //main
```

Comment: Your posted code seems unrelated to your problem statement. Could you elaborate with both lines of input?

Comment: what is the user input supposed to be? is it number or string??

Comment: Well What I want is it to have 2 players and they enter there wins like this: So if Player A: won twice they would put in AA.  And then if Player B won 5 times they would put in BBBBB:  Then it would say Player A: 2 Player B: 5

Comment: if _Player A_ will only enter letter `A`, and _Player B_ will only enter letter `B`, why don't just take the `length()`? `A.length()`, `B.length()` will give you the count

Comment: Ok So how would I add that to my code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this works for you perfectly

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
         System.out.println("Enter Player A value");

         String A = kb.nextLine();
         calsi(A); 

         System.out.println("Enter Player B value");
         String B = kb.nextLine();
         calsi(B); 
    }

    public static void calsi(String cmdVal){

        if (cmdVal.length()>0) { 
            String firstletter=cmdVal.substring(0,1);
            System.err.println(firstletter+":"+cmdVal.length());
        }else{
            System.err.println("No input has given"); 
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use Guava, it is dead simple; use a `CharMatcher`.

For instance, for matching character `A`, you'd create:

```
private static final CharMatcher UPPERCASE_A = CharMatcher.is('A');
```

Then you'd use:

```
UPPERCASE_A.countIn(yourInput)
```

to count the number of occurrences of `A` in `yourInput`.

Otherwise, a simple loop over the string will do that for you. If Java 8, you can use `.chars()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code. But here, array is used to store all the characters of a line.

public static void main(String[] args) {

```
    Scanner kb = new Scanner(System.in);
    String A = kb.nextLine();
    char[] chars = A.toCharArray(); 
    int count=0;
    for(int i=0;i<chars.length;i++){
        if(chars[i]=='A'){
            count++;
        }
    }

    System.out.println(count);
    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Could you do it with a Line Scanner?

Comment: @BenjaminMcIntyre Line Scanner? You mean, do you want to hard code the whole String(AAAA or BBB) or you want to enter one by one from Console?